# disable tooltip text form link

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I am creating a simple tooltip plugin, which shows "title" attribute contents as tooltip text.   So I want to disable the default browser behavior of showing the tooltip as I am displaying it in a `div`.  So I used the code below, but this doesn't work and I can see the default tooltip and my tooltip both together, default tooltip overlaps mine tooltip.

```
$("a").hover(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();   
});
```

Comment: why re-invent the wheel pal? try this one. http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just ensure that there are no `alt` and `title` attributes in the `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="http://google.com" alt="Google!" title="Google!" />Goto Google</a>
```

Changes to -

```
<a href="http://google.com" alt="Google!"  />Goto Google</a>
```

​
So all you have to do is run this jQuery code on all the `<a>` tags you want to remvove the default tooltip behavior on -

```
$(".desiredElements").removeProp('alt').removeProp('title');
```

---

If you want to maintain those tooltips for use at a later stage, you should save them in the `$.data` object, and return the values in the second hover function, the "hover out" callback.

```
$('.desiredElements').hover(function() {
    $thisCached = $(this);
    $.data(this, 'title', $thisCached.attr('title'));
    $thisCached.removeAttr('title').removeAttr('alt');
},function(){
    $thisCached = $(this);
    $thisCached.attr('title',$.data(this, 'title');
    $thisCached.attr('alt',$.data(this, 'title');
});
```

Comment: This is easiest way to assign tooltil contents, there isnt any way to remve default tooltip ?? if so then i will have to think on ur suggestion :)

Comment: removeprop will remove the contents of "title" and "alt" and i will not have anything to show in my tooltip.

Comment: @www - Oh! I see now, you only want to temporarily disable them... Maybe *these* edits will help you.

Comment: Thanks man ur idea worked. I couldnt use ur code as it is but i got the idea. Thanks, And ur coding style is great, looks like expert style. wish i could also write code like you.